# When taking 2 combinations of cards from the same deck, why don't you need to multiply by the order in which you could draw the cards?

Tags: probability, combinations

So I'm finding the probability that, given a deck with 1 jack removed, you will pick exactly 2 other jacks out of 4 cards drawn. I figured that you would simply take the number of ways you can get 2 jacks, multiplied by the number of ways you can get 2 non-jacks, multiplied by the number of ways you can order those draws, divided by the total number of possible 4-card hands:
$$
\frac{{3 \choose 2}\cdot{48 \choose 2}\cdot{4 \choose 2}}{51 \choose 4} = 0.081 (incorrect)
$$
However, simulation reveals that the correct answer does not multiply by the number of ways you can order those draws:
$$
\frac{{3 \choose 2}\cdot{48 \choose 2}}{51 \choose 4} = 0.014 (correct)
$$
How is it that this accounts for the possible orders of the draws?

Answer (score 0):

Notice the denominator $51 \choose 4$ is unordered. Hence for the numerator, we need not consider the order of the draw.

If we consider order in our calculation, we should in fact multiply by $4!$ rather than $4 \choose 2$ because each of the 4 cards drawn is unique. Similarly, the denominator will be multiplied by the same factor $4!$ accounting for order and these cancel out.